# Creating button style using metro button

Tags: wpf, button, microsoft-metro

I have this set of resources that I use in order to create a button style that changes image on a button when hovering, clicking and the idle state.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="LoginIdle" Source="/content/images/btn-login-idle.png" />
        <Image x:Key="LoginHover" Source="/content/images/btn-login-hover.png" />
        <Image x:Key="LoginActive" Source="/content/images/btn-login-active.png" />

        <Style x:Key="LoginButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource LoginIdle}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource LoginIdle}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource LoginActive}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

I tried putting in on the button.

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource LoginButtonStyle}" Name="LoginButton" Click="LoginBtn_Click">
    </Button>
```

The problem is, the image is not there.

I also tried setting a content value on the button and just change the images on the back-end code, but when I try to make the background Transparent, there is a border surrounding my image. I think this is because of the natural behavior of a button. Not really sure.

[image]

In conclusion, what I want to accomplish is add a idle image on a button, change image when hovering, pressing and leaving the button.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the images not there? Or only the Idle one?

If only the Idle Image is not there, have you tried setting the background property instead of the Content property before your triggers? And use a dynamic resource like in your triggers?

Comment: I cannot see any image at all. i even tried hovering it.

Comment: Try using an ImageBrush instead of an Image. And are you sure you have the right paths for your images?

Comment: Tried changing the content to background on my setter. Still no image. i'm sure of the path because when I try to set the content value of the button using static resource and my image key. the image shows as seen in my post. I'm relatively new at wpf. Will do a quick search on using ImageBrush. Thanks for the advices.

Comment: Fixed it, I added this code. <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in the answer to my question. After doing additional research. I found out that I need to add this line inside the ControlTemplate.

```
<ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Then all triggers works fine.